# js split() using regex, what expression was matched

Tags: javascript, regex, split

When using a regex as the separator in the `split()`, is there a way to know what string it matched?

Example:

```
var
    string     = "12+34-12",
    numberlist = split(/[^0-9]/);
```

how would I know if it found a `+` or a `-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use capturing group to also capture string that was used in `String#split`:

```
var m = string.split(/(\D)/);
//=> ["12", "+", "34", "-", "12"]
```

To see the difference here is the output without capturing group:

```
var m = string.split(/\D/);
//=> ["12", "34", "12"]
```

**PS:** I have changed your use of `[^0-9]` to `\D` since they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @zx81 for encouraging words.

Answer (score 3):

Just capture the splitting regular expression, like

```
numberlist = string.split(/([^0-9])/);
```

and the output will be

```
[ '12', '+', '34', '-', '12' ]
```

Since you are capturing the splitting regular expression, it will also be a part of the resulting array.